# Flutter Background operation on SQLite database

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-pub, sqflite

I'm trying to make a flutter app that stores the medicine and doctor appointment reminders for elderly people. I'm storing the data in the SQLite database.

What I need to achieve is, I'll explain with an example.

**If a person sets a reminder to take a medicine for like 6 pm he will get a notification to take the medicine at that time. If the person clicks on the notification and marks that he has taken it, then nothing happens. Else if the person clicks on "No" or if he ignores or does not give input like yes or no for like 1 hour or so, the relatives associated with the elder person will get an SMS stating that they have missed their medication.**

I already have the notification working. All I need to send SMS if there is no input or the elder chooses "NO" and do nothing when the elder chooses "YES".

I hope I made my question clear. Please do say If I need to explain it a bit more or for code that I already have.

I'm using Twilio for the SMS part. When the elder installs the app he has to give at least a phone number of one relative so that all this is possible.

How can I implement this?

PS: Give a detailed explanation. That would help a great bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try [background fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) plugin?
I guess you store due date or deadline... thing like that in your local db?
By checking periodicaly this time, you can verify if user see the notification or not and you will trigger sms.
Other workaround is to send push notification and wait a bit (1h in your case) and after send sms if no response from user (you must programaticaly send response back to your server if user says yes)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will check it out.